# After getting ajax success datatable's layout gets changed

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable, datatables

I am trying to solve an issue in which I am deleting and updating multiple rows in the data table but when I click on the multiple delete or multiple update button after getting ajax success my data table layout gets changed. I don't understand why this happening. I am not able to find any solution regarding this.
[image: Before ajax success]
[image: After ajax success]

**ajax for multiple delete**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{ route('website.multiple-deleterow') }}",
    data: {ids: delid, '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            console.log(data.data);
            $('#webite_table_list').html(data.data);
            myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtipl',
                lengthMenu: [ [ 25, 50,100,500, -1], [25, 50,100,500,'All' ] ],
                buttons: [
                {   
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    extend:'excel',
                    className: 'simple-export d-none',
                    title: 'Link Publisher',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    // action : newExportActionWebsite,
                    text:'<img src="{{asset('template_elsner/images/excel.svg')}}" /><b>Export</b>',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
                    },
                },{   
                    className: 'export-all',
                    text:'<img src="{{asset('template_elsner/images/excel.svg')}}" /><b>Export</b>',
                    action: function () {
                        window.location.href = '{{ route("all.website.excel")}}';
                        $('.export-all').addClass('d-none');
                            $('.simple-export').removeClass('d-none');
                        }},
                    ],
                });
            }
        }, 
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Something went wrong please try again.");
        }
    });
} else {
    alert("Please select atleast one checkbox");
}}
});
```

**Ajax for multiple status updates**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{ route('website.multiple-statusupdate') }}",
    data: {ids: delid,selected_status: selected_status, '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            console.log(data.data)
            $('#webite_table_list').html(data.data);
            myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtipl', 
                lengthMenu: [ [ 25, 50,100,500, -1], [25, 50,100,500,'All' ]],
                buttons: [
                {
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    extend:'excel',
                    className: 'simple-export d-none',
                    title: 'Link Publisher',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    // action : newExportActionWebsite,
                    text:'<img src="{{asset('template_elsner/images/excel.svg')}}" /><b>Export</b>',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
                    },
                },
                {   
                    className: 'export-all',
                    text:'<img src="{{asset('template_elsner/images/excel.svg')}}" /><b>Export</b>',
                    action: function ()
                        {
                            window.location.href = '{{ route("all.website.excel")}}';
                            $('.export-all').addClass('d-none');
                            $('.simple-export').removeClass('d-none');
                        }
                },
                ],
            });     
        }   
    }, 
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Something went wrong please try again.");
    }
});
```

**datatable**

```
myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtipl',
    lengthMenu: [ [ 25, 50,100,500, -1], [25, 50,100,500,'All' ] ],
    buttons: [
    {
        pageSize: 'LEGAL',
        extend:'excel',
        className: 'simple-export d-none',
        title: 'Link Publisher',
        orientation: 'landscape',
        // action : newExportActionWebsite,
        text:'<img src="{{asset('template_elsner/images/excel.svg')}}" /><b>Export</b>',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
        },
    },
    {   
        className: 'export-all',
        text:'<img src="{{asset('template_elsner/images/excel.svg')}}" /><b>Export</b>',
        action: function ()
        {
            window.location.href = '{{ route("all.website.excel")}}';
            $('.export-all').addClass('d-none');
            $('.simple-export').removeClass('d-none');
        }
    },
],
                
// dom: 't',
"serverSide": true,
"responsive": true,
"bDestroy": true,
'ajax': {
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '{{ route("websites.website_list") }}',
    data: function (d) {
        d.sort= sort;
        d.start_date= start_date;
        d.end= end;
        d.user_id= userId;
    }
},
            "colReorder": true,
            "order": [],
            'columns': [
                
            { 'data': '', 'name': '', "defaultContent": ""},
            {
            data: null,
            name: '',
            render: data => {
                return '<input class="ms-checkbox-wrap ms-checkbox-danger checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delid[]" value="'+data.id+'">';
            }
            },
            { 'data': 'username', 'name': 'username'},
            { 'data': 'website_url_value', 'name': 'website_url_value'},
            { 'data': 'da', 'name': 'da'},
            { 'data': 'traffic', 'name': 'traffic', "sType": "numeric"},
            // { 'data': 'website_name', 'name': 'website_name' },
            { 'data': 'website_category', 'name': 'website_category' },
            { 'data': 'backlink_type', 'name': 'backlink_type' },
            { 'data': 'tat', 'name': 'tat'},
            { 'data': 'sample_post', 'name': 'sample_post' },
            { 'data': 'guidelines', 'name': 'guidelines' },
            { 'data': 'publishing_price', 'name': 'publishing_price'},
            { 'data': 'person', 'name': 'person'},
            { 'data': 'total_order', 'name': 'total_order' },
            { 'data': 'amt_receive', 'name': 'amt_receive' },
            { 'data': 'amt_paid', 'name': 'amt_paid' },
            { 'data': 'profilt', 'name': 'profilt' },
            { 'data': 'refund', 'name': 'refund' },
            { 'data': 'grade', 'name': 'grade' },
            { 'data': 'estimate_grade', 'name': 'estimate_grade' },
            { 'data': 'status_datatable', 'name': 'status_datatable', orderable: false, searchable: false },                
            { 'data': 'tag_name','name':'tag_name'},
            { 'data': 'tag_email','name':'tag_email'},
            { 'data': 'linkinsertion_price', 'name': 'linkinsertion_price'},
            { 'data': 'action', 'name': 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
            {targets: [0], orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {targets: [1], orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {targets: [8], render: function(data){return data.replace("_", " ");}},
            {targets: [11], render: function(data){return "$"+data;}},
            {targets: [12], render: function(data){return data;}},
            {targets: [14], render: function(data){if(data==null){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
            {targets: [15], render: function(data){if(data==null){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
             {targets: [16], render: function(data){if(data==0){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
            {targets: [17], render: function(data){if(data==0){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
            ],
            fixedColumns: true,
            select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:nth-of-type(2)'
            },
            "initComplete": function()
            {
                var timer = 0;
                $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind('.DT').bind('keyup.DT', function(e)
                {
                    var value = this.value;
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = setTimeout(function() {
                        myTable.search(value).draw();
                    }, 1000);
                    return;
                });
            }
});
```

Comment: try myTable.reload() after update

Comment: I tried but it's not working. again getting the changed layout after success call

Comment: layout changes means what exactly ? is it css issue or any other ?

Comment: i don't think it's css issue. last two columns get hidden and goes to child row. after ajax success.

Comment: once you try removing all datatable code from success and just try myTable.reload()

Comment: keeps reloading when I try that. nothing shows.

Comment: try myTable.ajax.reload();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234845/discussion-between-divyesh-and-john-lobo).

Comment: it's working but showing all columns now. no child rows https://prnt.sc/1b0eqml

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to solve it.
Actually, the problem was before ajax success the URL was getting load without domain and after the success, it was showing full URL with https/http/www so I removed the domain and all

```
<td>
                <a href="{{$data->website_url}}" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" target="_blank" class="url_website order-anchor" id="website_{{$data->id}}">
                    
                    <?php
                    $pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
                    $url = $data->website_url;
                    if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) === 1) {
                        ?>
                        {{ $matches[0] }}
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    
                </a>
            </td>
```

and so column width was changing after success so to solve it, I set the column width also after ajax success.

```
"columnDefs": [
            {width: 16,targets: [0], orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {width: 28,targets: [1], orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {width: 51, targets: [2]},
            {width: 88, targets: [3]},
            {width: 22, targets: [4]},
            {width: 63, targets: [5]},
            {width: 29,targets: [8], render: function(data){return data.replace("_", " ");}},
            {width: 39,targets: [11], render: function(data){return "$"+data;}},
            {width: 72,targets: [12], render: function(data){return data;}},
            {targets: [14], render: function(data){if(data==null){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
            {targets: [15], render: function(data){if(data==null){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
            {targets: [16], render: function(data){if(data==0){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
            {targets: [17], render: function(data){if(data==0){ return 0; } else { return "$"+data;}}},
            {width: 130,targets: [20], orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {width: 66,targets: [24], orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ],
```